How to retrieve id from chunk in Azure AI Search index via Langchain
I have documents uploaded to the Azure AI Search index. Each of the documents automatically gets an id. How can i retrieve all documents with ids via langchain?
I tried with a from langchain_community.vectorstores import AzureSearch creating a vectorstore client and using .search method. It retrieves me the documents but not the id. When i access doc.id its value = None.

You will get results like below.
[Document(metadata={'id': 'ZjE4YzBkNmQtNzkyNi00NDFjLWJkY2YtMWQyNzUyNTRiYzdh', 'title': 'Title 3', 'source': 'B', 'random': '32893'}, page_content='Test 3'),
 Document(metadata={'id': 'Mjc0ZjE0ZTktYzUxNS00ZDgxLTg1NmQtZjJhMjM5MjNkYzli', 'title': 'Title 1', 'source': 'A', 'random': '10290'}, page_content='Test 1'),
 Document(metadata={'id': 'ZDIzZjIzY2EtZjBhMi00ODhjLWIzZjktYjM0MjlkMjBjMWNl', 'title': 'Title 2', 'source': 'A', 'random': '48392'}, page_content='Test 2')]

and id field will be in metadata object and not in document object.

So, access it like below.
print(res[0].metadata['id'])

Also, make sure you have id field in your index.

The id gets automatically populated by the Index and not by me.

Tried above solution. Is it working?

Yeah Id field is the key, automatically created for every record.

As the id ist automatically created i cannot access the value during the indexing process to save it into the metadata

You should access in the results of your query search not while Indexing.is this you mentioned in question right? Search method results not having id

As in my question written. I want to retrieve the id within the search method.

Yes. You get the results from search method and access it like above. If  you still can't find please add the ouput of the  results from search method like this print(client.search(<your query>))
